# How to change an IIFE with an argument to ES6.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am new to ES6 and converting some old code to ES6.I have some ES5 code where I override some jquery methodslike below:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.val = function() {
    };  
}(jQuery) ---> I'm getting a ESlint 'no-undef' 'jQuery' is not defined error.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to add `jQuery` to the globals of your `.eslintrc`

Comment: If you'll install jQuery via npm you can import or require it, and the ESLint error will disappear. - `import jquery from "jquery";` or `const jquery = require("jquery");`

Comment: Thank you @Ori Drori. That worked.